# pod lib lint fails implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcodebuild

I tried to declare this macro on my `prefix.pch` file which works great on XCode and passes validation on travis.

my macro looks like:

`#ifndef RELEASE`

`#define DLog(__FORMAT__, ...) NSLog((@"%s [Line %d] " __FORMAT__), __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)`

`#else`

`#define DLog(...)`

`#endif`

MY `PodSpec` file this:

> Pod::Spec.new do |s|
>
> s.name         = "MyExampleProject"
>   s.version      = "1.0.1"
>   s.summary      = "XXX"
>
> s.homepage     = "XXXXXX"
>
> s.license      = {:type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE.md' }
>
> s.author       = { "XX" => "XX@XX.com" }
>
> s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
>
> s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/XX/XX.git", :branch => "master", :tag => s.version }
>
> s.source_files  = "MyExampleProject/**/*.{h,m}"
>   s.public_header_files = "MyExampleProject/***/.{h}"
>
> s.requires_arc = true
>   end

When running `pod lib lint MyExampleProject.podspec` I get:

`MyExampleProject (1.0.1)`

`- ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code. You can use`--verbose`for more information.`

`- WARN  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ../MyExampleClass.m:87:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'DLog' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer here: 
[apptentive-ios](https://github.com/apptentive/apptentive-ios/blob/Next/apptentive-ios.podspec)

I needed to manually add the contents of my `prefix.pch` as for some reason xcodebuild was not reading from it. In my case, I moved the content of the `prefix.pch` to the unmbrella header.

This is how my `podspec` looks now:

> Pod::Spec.new do |s|
>
> s.name         = "MyExampleProject"
>   s.version      = "1.0.1"
>   s.summary      = "XXX"
>
> s.homepage     = "XXXXXX"
>
> s.license      = {:type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE.md' }
>
> s.author       = { "XX" => "XX@XX.com" }
>
> s.platform     = :ios, "8.0"
>
> s.source       = { :git => "https://github.com/XX/XX.git", :branch => "master", :tag => s.version }
>
> `s.prefix_header_contents = '#import "MyExampleProject.h"'`
>
> s.source_files  = "MyExampleProject/**/*.{h,m}"
>   s.public_header_files = "MyExampleProject/***/.{h}"
>
> s.requires_arc = true
>   end

The full project can be seen here: [EasyDoanloadSession](http://git@github.com:lagubull/EasyDownloadSession.git)